# Symfony routing: adding sf_method [get] requirement

Tags: security, symfony1, routes

I'm reading the book Practical Symfony, and there is a part in the book which suggests adding sf_method: [get] to routing.yml for pages which contain single job description.

My question is somewhat general: should i always add the requirement

```
sf_method: [get]
```

to routes linking to a description of a particular object (in this case job)?

And the reason behind adding this line is primarily security, or are there more reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unneccessary. Routes linking to a single object (assumung you're using `sfDoctrineRoute` or `sfPropelRoute`) only have `get` as a requirement by default. If you want to post to that url, for example, you need to explicity add `[get, post]` as the sf_method requirement.

Comment: I think it's default even for sfRoute routes

Comment: sfRoute has no requirements at all, see [sfRoute, line 35](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php#L35)